# Controlling 4 BLDC motors with a Raspberry Pi Model 4B

Tags: motor, raspberry-pi, brushless-dc-motor, drone, quad-copter

I am fairly new to electronics and have been working on a quadcopter project using the Raspberry Pi 4B. I am currently trying to figure out the best way to control four BLDC motors and would appreciate any advice you may have.

I have come across a few options, such as using two L293D chips with an H-bridge or using the [ZeroBorg Basic - Quad Motor Controller](https://www.piborg.org/motor-control-1135/zeroborg-ks1). After some consideration, I have decided to go with the ZeroBorg option since it has fewer parts and would be easier to fit compared to using two L293Ds.

However, I have noticed that the ZeroBorg has blocks of two screw input terminals, and I have seen people using three inputs per motor in my research. This has left me feeling confused and unsure about how to approach the problem. [My motor specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dI35.png).

My ultimate goal is to have a circuit(smaller/cheaper the better) that I can fully access through the Raspberry Pi and use to adjust the speed and direction of all four motors individually. I would be extremely grateful for any pointers on how to achieve this. Any specific details are also welcome!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The ZeroBorg's *4 full H-Bridges* is enough to control speed&direction of four *brushed* motors. Owning four PMSM/BLDC motors, look for BLDC controllers.

Comment: This probably is a better fit for [Drones and Model Aircraft@SE](https://drones.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I didn't know of this community before, thanks @greybeard!